# Service worker should not cache the whole page

Tags: caching, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I register '/' (route) .css and .js file as URL that should be cached at first.

But after that I realize that it cached the whole page, which means I don't see any update on my view, event there is an update on database.

So I change it only cache my .css and .js file not route ('/') anymore , I expected that's the problem.

But after awhile, the same problem still occurred. I check on my console it did cache the whole page again, even though my Service Worker file already change like this:

```
var CACHE_NAME = 'cache-v2';
var urlsToCache = [
  '/assets/css/app.css',
  '/assets/js/main.js',
  '/assets/js/other.js'
];

self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
      .then(function(cache) {
        console.log('Opened cache');
        return cache.addAll(urlsToCache);
      })
  );
});

self.addEventListener('activate', function(e) {
  console.log('[ServiceWorker] Activate');
  e.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then(function(keyList) {
      return Promise.all(keyList.map(function(key) {
        if (key !== CACHE_NAME) {
          console.log('[ServiceWorker] Removing old cache', key);
          return caches.delete(key);
        }
      }));
    })
  );
  return self.clients.claim();
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.match(event.request)
      .then(function(response) {
        // Cache hit - return response
        if (response) {
          return response;
        }

        var fetchRequest = event.request.clone();

        return fetch(fetchRequest).then(
          function(response) {

            if(!response || response.status !== 200 || response.type !== 'basic') {
              return response;
            }

            var responseToCache = response.clone();

            caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
              .then(function(cache) {
                cache.put(event.request, responseToCache);
              });

            return response;
          }
        );
      })
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

in case anyone has the same problem,
here is what i should change

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(e) {
  console.log('[ServiceWorker] Fetch', e.request.url);
  e.respondWith(
    caches.match(e.request).then(function(response) {
      return response || fetch(e.request);
    })
  );
});
```

so my previous fetch looks like the problem